# Rails 3. the "flash" doesn't work on some pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

I'm using the "web_app_theme" gem. The problem is that the flash error and warning messages don't work.

For example, in the Sign In page it does work; but in the Forgot Password page it doesn't work. I tested it by displaying the contents of the flash `<%= debug flash %>`.

This is what I get in the Sign In page...

```
!ruby/object:ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash
          used: !ruby/object:Set
            hash:
              :alert: true
          closed: false
          flashes:
            :alert: Invalid email or password.
          now: !ruby/object:ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashNow
```

But in the Forgot Password page I get...

```
!ruby/object:ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash
    used: !ruby/object:Set
      hash: {}
    closed: false
    flashes: {}
    now: !ruby/object:ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashNow
```

I'm thinking that it might be related to not using haml. In the Sign In page I'm using haml but in the Forgot Password page I'm using erb. I'm confused because the contents of 'flash' should be the same regardless of the format, right?

Answer (score 0):

This has little to with the view code you use.

From your question, it's clear that the flash in the Forgot Password page has not been set.
Either that or it has been set and erased. Using HAML or ERB is not relevant since the Rails flash is present in both pages.

Check the controller code for the same and verify what should be in the flash on that page.

Also, while there is no hard and fast rule, it is **strongly advised** to use only one template / view engine (erb or haml) in a single application.

Answer (score 0):

On the Forgot Password page, is the `flash` object being set and the page then rendered, or is it being set and then a *redirection* to the page happening?

The normal use case for `flash` is that you assign to it and then redirect to another page where flash is present. If you want to use `flash` and then display it's contents in the same action (such as then rendering a template)

Instead of writing (e.g.)

```
flash[:notice] = 'Foo Bar'
```

You write

```
flash.now[:notice] = 'Foo Bar'
```

Comment: Also, what are the expected contents of the flash object meant to be for the Forgot Password page? and are there any controller action code that you could provide, or is it all contained within that gem?